# MySql Databe - listing products that have only one category

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having-clause

I have table in database like:

```
===========================
products_id | categories_id
===========================
      1            2
      1            1
      1            3
      1            4
      1            5
      2            5
      2            2
      2            3
      2            4
      3            5
      4            5
      5            5 
===========================
```

I'm not so good in mysql so i need some help with this query. I want to list all `products_id` that have only `categories_id = 5`. That is, even if the `categories_id` is 5, it should only be listed if no other row exists with that `products_id` and a different `categories_id`.
So the output should be : `3 4 5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using aggregation and filtering with a `having` clause:

```
select product_id
from mytable
group by product_id
having min(category_id) = 5 and max(category_id) = min(category_id)
```